# Opencart Reward Point Calculation Rs 1 for every 10 points

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

I am using opencart for implementing my ecomm website. I have added reward feature in it. I want that if user has 500 points then it can be equivalent to Rs 50. But at present it is equal to 42.51. Can any one help me out on the same.

My code for reward point is :-

```
class ModelTotalReward extends Model {
public function getTotal(&$total_data, &$total, &$taxes) {
    if (isset($this->session->data['reward'])) {
        $this->load->language('total/reward');

        $points = $this->customer->getRewardPoints();

        if ($this->session->data['reward'] <= $points) {
            $discount_total = 0;

            $points_total = 0;

            foreach ($this->cart->getProducts() as $product) {
                if ($product['points']) {
                    $points_total += $product['points'];
                }
            }

            $points = min($points, $points_total);

            foreach ($this->cart->getProducts() as $product) {
                $discount = 0;

                if ($product['points']) {
                    $discount = $product['total'] * ($this->session->data['reward'] / $points_total);

                    if ($product['tax_class_id']) {
                        $tax_rates = $this->tax->getRates($product['total'] - ($product['total'] - $discount), $product['tax_class_id']);

                        foreach ($tax_rates as $tax_rate) {
                            if ($tax_rate['type'] == 'P') {
                                $taxes[$tax_rate['tax_rate_id']] -= $tax_rate['amount'];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                $discount_total += $discount;
            }

            $total_data[] = array(
                'code'       => 'reward',
                'title'      => sprintf($this->language->get('text_reward'), $this->session->data['reward']),
                'value'      => -$discount_total,
                'sort_order' => $this->config->get('reward_sort_order')
            );

            $total -= $discount_total;
        }
    }
}

public function confirm($order_info, $order_total) {
    $this->load->language('total/reward');

    $points = 0;

    $start = strpos($order_total['title'], '(') + 1;
    $end = strrpos($order_total['title'], ')');

    if ($start && $end) {
        $points = substr($order_total['title'], $start, $end - $start);
    }

    if ($points) {
        $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "customer_reward SET customer_id = '" . (int)$order_info['customer_id'] . "', order_id = '" . (int)$order_info['order_id'] . "', description = '" . $this->db->escape(sprintf($this->language->get('text_order_id'), (int)$order_info['order_id'])) . "', points = '" . (float)-$points . "', date_added = NOW()");
    }
}

public function unconfirm($order_id) {
    $this->db->query("DELETE FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "customer_reward WHERE order_id = '" . (int)$order_id . "' AND points < 0");
}
```

}